# NHibernate Prevent Lazy Loading of unmatched reference

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have quite a problem with NHibernate. I have a reference from Table1 to Table2, and I want NHibernate to, when a corresponding record is not found in Table2, to not then issue a SELECT statement against Table2, to, I don't know, make really really sure that it actually isn't there.

I've tried adding modifiers like `.LazyLoad(Laziness.False)` and `.NotFound.Ignore()` to my reference, but NHibernate gaily ignores my commands with extreme prejudice, issuing its select and breaking my code.

Comment: I don't understand... how should  NHibernate know that the record isn't there without issuing a SELECT to check for it?

Comment: Checking that the Left Join returns a NULL id, which I can only imagine is exactly what it does, since it only issues the SELECT when the JOIN comes back empty instead of leaving well enough alone.

Comment: NH doesn't caches the existence of objects. It doesn't cache the non-existence of objects. The hydration process (object instantiation) has to work even from an underlying result set where the referenced table isn't included.

Comment: `Ignore` is just a crutch for tolerating invalid foreign key values. But the root of the trouble is the invalid foreign key values. Keeping them in the DB exposes to issues like yours. Now if your can [contribute](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) a PR for avoiding those select, maybe it will be accepted. But since this would look as an optimization for a low usage feature, if that PR has big impacts, it will likely not be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct, that NHibernate tries to load "not existing". It **must** do that.

As stated here [Ayende - NHibernate Mapping](http://ayende.com/blog/3938/nhibernate-mapping-many-to-one) (an extract):

> 12) not-found is another **legacy** feature, it controls how NHibernate
>   behaves when it finds an invalid foreign key. That is, a value that
>   points to an entity that doesn’t exist. By default, this would trigger
>   an error, as this generally indicate a problem with the database, but
>   with legacy database, you can tell it to set the property value to
>   null instead.

And as could be found here: [Lazy loading for NHibernate with Ignore.NotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5666325/1679310) (an extract):

> When you specify the .NotFound().Ignore() this forces the entity to be
>   eagerly loaded and cannot be overriden with the .LazyLoad().
>   NHibernate does this because it has to be sure that relationship
>   exists or doesn't exist since you are not relying on the database to
>   enforce this.

And here [Why Nhibernate won't lazy load my many-to-one relationship?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/yT3Peh8bA_Q), José F. Romaniello says:

> This is your problem, nhibernate must to be sure, that an invoice
>   EXIST or do not exist for each enrollment.
>
> I'd strongly recommend you to fix your data problems and remove the
>   not-found="ignore" attribute. It is a bad thing.

Comment: I don't really see how or why NHibernate **MUST** do that. I'm left-joining, sometimes there's something there, sometimes there isn't, and if there was any way at all of disabling the extra select then there wouldn't be a problem at all. What does it matter to NHibernate whether or not my left joins yield values?

Comment: The real problem is in fact that your `Table1` has Column `Table2Id` filled, with a value not a NULL. This indicates that there must be  corresponding `ID` in the `Table2` (column `ID`). Only in case, the Table2Id is NULL is clear, there is no need to search for that reference. The solutions are 1) replace all not existing values in Table1 with NULL 2) introduce missing values into Table2. I understand that from your perspective it is not an issue... But maybe try to think how to do it "manually". How can one know, that the ID should not be searched?

Comment: Well, replacing the values or introducing the missing ones are sadly not options that will be viable. Only nh accepting that some joins will not yield results is going to work.

Comment: I was in the same situation as you. I bet on the `not-found="ignored"` and faced the same issue. Temp solution was some hardcoding but at the end "fixing" the DB was the way we've choosen

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom Alternatively, don't tell NHibernate about the relationship. Map it simply as e.g. integer, and do the querying yourself if you need to. What NHibernate does have nothing to do with left join in queries - it's when NH tries to instantiate the object that it aims to be sure that the other object either is or isn't there.

Comment: The thing is that the join needs to be there for later ordering, why it can't simply be selected.

Comment: I would say, Andreas, I really understand what you are trying. But as I treid to explain as an answer to your question, that's how the NHibernate behaves. I would strongly suggest, try to investigate the possiblities how to fix the DB, rather then tweak the NHiberante. but just a suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.Not.LazyLoad();
```

instead of .LazyLoad(laziness.false);

Comment: I did, doesn't work, and the help-text for `.LazyLoad()` mentions that it doesn't work with `.Not`