# NHibernate, how to disable additional selects for orphaned references

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, nhibernate-mapping, eager-loading

I'm using NHibernate for data access and have a situation like this

```cs
public class B
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set;}
   // ...
}
public class B
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set;}
   public virtual A AReference { get; set; }
   // ...
}
```

and mapping

```cs
public class BMapping : ClassMapping<B>
{
    // ...
        ManyToOne(x => x.AReference, mapper =>
        {
            mapper.ForeignKey("none");
            mapper.Insert(false);
            mapper.Update(false);
            mapper.Column("a_id");
            mapper.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
            mapper.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore);
        });
    // ...
}
```

My problem is that there is no foreign key constraint between table`A` and `tableB`, so there are cases where `tableB` references nonexistent items. *(I know that's bad, but I can't do anything about it.)*

Setting

```cs
mapper.NotFound(NotFoundMode.Ignore);
```

allows me to retrieve data without "No row with the given identifier exists" exceptions, but it seems NHibernate is trying to load those orphaned items using separate selects like

```sql
SELECT ... FROM tableA WHERE tableA.ID = ?
```

Can I disable that additional queries and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed here [NHibernate Prevent Lazy Loading of unmatched reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18652419/1679310) and here [Lazy loading for NHibernate with Ignore.NotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5663548/1679310) the point is:

> When you specify the .NotFound().Ignore() this forces the entity to be eagerly loaded and cannot be overriden with the .LazyLoad(). NHibernate does this because it has to be sure that relationship exists or doesn't exist since you are not relying on the database to enforce this.

Check this for

- [NHibernate force not-found ignore to not execute an extra select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726668/1679310)

and mostly the link provided there

#### [How to use 0 instead of null for foreign keys](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.html)

to get some understanding how to create custom PocoEntityTuplizer to be used that.

> .. during the build process of the Person entity will collection object[] values contain also CountryProxy. Let's say that missing in DB is one with Id == 0 (use your own logic there as needed). This proxy will be replaced with null so no SELECT will be executed...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Implemented my PocoEntityTuplizer, but seems that the selects are done right before reaching SetPropertyValues(object entity, object[] values). I mean I've something like  `code`        public override void SetPropertyValues(object entity, object[] values)
        {
            var aId = ((int?) values[14]);
            if (aId.HasValue && aId.Value == 333)
            {
                values[25] = null;
            }
            base.SetPropertyValues(entity, values);
        }`code`, where 333 is an orphan id. So the select ... where id = 333 is done before that.

Comment: Hard to find what's wrong. Sorry for this suggestion, but be patient and try check all your settings. Because this approach is working.. not easy but is. And really the only way. I can hardly assist more on your own code...

Comment: yeah, setting NotFoundMode.Exception instead of ignore helped, now working. You saved my day, thanks again.

Comment: It is so great to see. I am so glad that you did not give up.. and you made it. Enjoy amazing NHibernate, sir! ;)